# Wordpress loop.php functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, styles

I'm new to wordpress, but I've done PHP for a little while.

Is the loop.php EXCLUSIVELY just for displaying blog posts...or does it have other useful functionality for pages as well?

I'm using a theme, and most of the pages have ...

```
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
```

... in them. This is not a blog site and I don't need blog posts displayed. I do want other web content where this is displaying on the page.

Is it proper WP coding style to use the loop for content, even if its not a blog site? Or can I just remove the line and replace it with page code?

Thanks!

Comment: PS...I created a page test.php contaaining only...

    <?php>
    echo "test";
    <?>

...and added it to the home.php using get_template_part('test') and it works. So I'm not sure what the issue is with the other pages....?

Instead of hacking pages out manually...is there a link describing how I can create a template using the wp-admin tools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page code isn't what **that code** replaces... More on **get_template_part**  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to answer. You know, I had found that link...and had tried to use the get_template_part to add other components to the page...but it wasn't working. 

I'm still trying to figure it out. For example, theres a component that came with the theme called "feedback.php". But when I try to add ...

    <?php get_template('feedback'); ?>

... OR ...

<?php get_template_part('demo'); ?>

...I get nothing. I've tried a couple of other templates that I THINK are valid, and none of them work. 

Sucks to be a noob :-)\

Comment: PS...I created a page test.php contaaining only...

    <?php>
    echo "test";
    <?>